Why is a Intel AX210 Wi-Fi 6E card not recognized by Linux?
I just bought an AX210NGW and installed it in my laptop motherboard, however I am having some issues with it: Linux simply does not recognize it. I attach the description of my machine below.

Product name: S14BW01;
Processor type: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3060 @ 1.60GHz; And
Previous wireless card: Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 3160NGW.

Below are the settings of my OS.
# uname-a
Linux myusername 6.8.0-31-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Apr 20 00:40:06 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

And below the lspci result.
# lspci     
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 35)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 35)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SATA Controller (rev 35)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 35)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 35)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 35)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 (rev 35)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #2 (rev 35)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #3 (rev 35)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 35)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller (rev 35)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)

The command lshw, shows AX210 as a bluetooth device, which I think it is expected.
# lshw
...
*-usb
description: Bluetooth wireless interface
    product: AX210 Bluetooth
vendor: Intel Corp.
    physical id: 2
bus info: usb@1:5.2
    version: 0.00
capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.01
    configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
...

The ifconfig returns the following output.
# ifconfig
ens1f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.214  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::54da:ba7:9ccd:4102  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a02:1811:d3a:c800:934f:84c1:c351:77ea  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2a02:1811:d3a:c800:d83:cbc1:1fb8:1bf8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 80:ee:73:d0:41:8f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 38470  bytes 39115681 (39.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7418  bytes 1945697 (1.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
 
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2293  bytes 179808 (179.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2293  bytes 179808 (179.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
 
virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:cb:d3:c9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

The hwinfo returns the following.
# hwinfo --network --short
network interface:
  ens1f1               Ethernet network interface
  lo                   Loopback network interface
  virbr0               Ethernet network interface

The dmesg returns the following.
# dmesg | grep wifi

# dmesg | grep wire

The rfkill results are:
# rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked

Do I have to install the drivers? I mean, as far as I know, in order to install the drivers, the computer must at least be able to "see" the device, is my reasoning right?

Here are the pictures of the old device, the Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 3160NGW.


And here are the pictures of the new device, the Intel AX210NGW Wi-Fi 6E.



Here are the screenshots of the BIOS setup.


Device control submenu:

Trusted computing submenu:





That kernel (6.8) has drivers for that chipset embedded in it... I suspect something else is going on here as the BT is seen (same chipset) but the WiFi portion. I would suspect this is a BIOS setting perhaps? "Enable embedded WiFi adapter" or something similar, but you didn't really state your mainboard/laptop make or model. Some models also have BIOS "whitelists" for WiFi chipsets and will not initialize them, although the general throw an error in the BIOS boot screen noting so.

Aren't the BT bits usually connected via USB? Also, if its a really new card there may not be drivers - the HWE kernel might help. also I can't remember for the life of me where I documented this but a card with missing drivers won't turn up. I had a small heart attack when a buggy kernel made half the ports on one of my systems vanish.

@acejavelin, thanks for the comment. I contacted the manufacturer, and they simply said they didn't had any information for this kind of cusomization, so I tried at my own risk. Concerning the BIOS settings, the only options, I think make sense to change, are the "fast boot" and "secure boot", so far I had disabled the fast boot, and it is still not working, but I will try the secure boot off, and then I come back here.

@JourneymanGeek thanks for the comment. I also got lost about the BT USB info, and I do not know the answer for your question. Concerning the drivers, I downloaded the file iwlwifi-ty-59.601f3a66.0.tgz at (intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html), and moved its inner files as suggested: cp iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode /lib/firmware. But, no changes, even after rebooting. Is there any additional step after copying this file?

@acejavelin, btw, I am using Lubuntu, and I've just tried to load it in live mode in an USB stick, and the lubuntu wasn't able to identify the wireless card as well. I will try with tails, then I come back here.

No sucess with tails as well. I will check with other Linux OSs.

The fact it's not showing up in lspci indicates the kernel doesn't see it, but the Bluetooth is "AX210" chipset, which (if correct) has been supported in kernel since 5.10. If the adapter isn't recognized or seen in lspci, then there are limited possible issues here... The adapter is too new for the kernel and not actually an AX210 (possible, but unlikely)... The adapter is disabled by BIOS or key combo (likely)... The adapter is not the stock one and the device has a whitelist that is blocking it (unlikely)... The adapter isn't connected properly (unlikely)... or it's defective.

Maybe PHYSICALLY examine the module and reseat it... most are labeled quite well, examine it and make sure you are chasing the correct adapter. You could also check rfkill although I doubt that will show anything.

@acejavelin, thanks for the comments. Well, I've just replaced back the AX210NGW to the 3160NGW, and it is working just now, using the same antena cables order. For a better diagnostic, I attached the pictures of both devices, front and back view. Thanks and regards.

Not sure what to say... they both use the same iwlwifi kernel module (driver), the only difference is the firmware file (which ALL supported Intel adapters are included with the kernel module package). The kernel "sees" the adapter in the hardware detection process at boot, and loads the driver, it's all automated. Is it seen in BIOS/UEFI firmware?

Thanks for the support. I've attached the screenshots of the BIOS setup, and also the output of the rfkill command.

Perhaps, this is really a limitation on the BIOS whitelist. After searching for strategies for removing the BIOS whitelist, I couldn't find any resource available for my machine, so, do you think that trying a coreboot or libreboot would be a feasible try?

I suggest to look for "Intel", "AX210" and "firmware" in dmesg output. Inability to load a firmware is usually a cause of similar issues.
Unfortunately, there are more bad news - Linux drivers for this chipset are far from perfect and active use of Wifi and BT at the same time will quickly (hours) cause BT to fail and require a restart (at least of btusb module).
